# C++ error: expected initialiser before 'class'

Tags: c++

When I compile the program I am working on I get:

> expected initializer before 'class'

error in my `Class.h` file. I looked up the error message on the internet, but couldn't find the exact error, although similar errors seem to be caused by missing semicolons but I don't see why I need one. This is the code the error points to, I have no other functions or classes before it.

```
class Account
{
    public:
    double dAccountBalance;

    double dAccountChange(double dChange);
};
```

In the `Class.cpp` file the `double dAccountChange(double dChange)` function is defined. I don't think this is where the error is coming from but this is the code;

```
double Account::dAccountChange(double dChange)
{
    dAccountBalance += dChange;

    return 0.0;
}
```

When I change the code in Class.h to look like this,

```
;
class Account
{
    public:
    double dAccountBalance;

    double dAccountChange(double dChange);
};
```

it doesn't generate an error message, but I can't work out why I need the semicolon before it as the only code I have before it are the following pre-processor lines.

```
#ifndef CLASS_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASS_H_INCLUDED
```

Any ideas on why the error is generated?

Comment: One of your headers seems to be missing a semicolon.

Comment: Can you paste in the *exact* error message, complete with line numbers? Because there's something we're missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in one of the *other* headers, one that you #include ahead of `class.h`.

If you show us the top of your main `cpp` file, it might give a clue.

Comment: this code? `#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#include "Class.h"`

Comment: Thanks: yes, those are completely standard. Therefore we're looking in the wrong place: please edit your question to include the *exact* compiler error(s) and warning(s), complete with line number(s).

Comment: The compiler only displays the error message; error: expected initializer before 'class'
on line 5, the `class Account` code.

Comment: I'm using the codeblocks GNU GCC compiler. Sorry about the mistake in the previous comment, pressed enter accidently before I had finished typing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in one of the '#include' files in the C++ standard library? Not the .h files I wrote, but the ones like <iostream> and <cstdio>.

Comment: The odds of it being one of the standard libraries are almost nil. Do your other projects build correctly?

Answer (score 10):

Most likely, in the header file you include immediately *before* `class.h`, you'll have something like:

```
class xyzzy {
    int plugh;
}
```

*without* the closing semi-colon. That will make your code sequence:

```
class xyzzy {
    int plugh;
}
class Account
{
    public:
    double dAccountBalance;

    double dAccountChange(double dChange);
};
```

which is clearly invalid. Inserting a semi-colon in `class.h` before the first line will fix it, but it's clearly the wrong place to put it (since it means *every* header file you include immediately after that one would need a starting semicolon - also, it's part of the definition in the first header and should be there).

Now that may not be the exact code sequence but it will be something very similar, and the underlying reason will be a missing piece of text in the *previous* header.

You should go back and put it in the *earlier* include file.

For example, consider:

```
include1.h:
    class xyzzy {
        int plugh;
    }
include2.h:
    class twisty {
        int little_passages;
    };
main.cpp:
    #include "include1.h"
    #include "include2.h"
    int main (void) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiling this produces:

```
include2.h:3: error: multiple types in one declaration
```

but placing the semicolon at the end of `include1.h` (or start of `include2.h` though we've already established that's not a good idea) will fix it.